# Scala/Akka Future onComplete Success compiler error

Tags: scala, akka, actor, future

I have an actor that waits for the results of a future.  Calling onComplete of the future causes a compiler error:

> error: constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type
>   [scalac]  found   : akka.actor.Status.Success
>      [scalac]  required: scala.util.Try[Iterable[Any]]
>      [scalac]         case Success(result: List[PCBInstanceStats]) => {
>      [scalac]              ^

Actor's receive:

```
case "pcbStatus" => {
      val future = Future.traverse(context.children)(x => {
        (x ? "reportStatus")(5 seconds)
      })

      future.onComplete {
        case Success(result: List[PCBInstanceStats]) => {
          self ! result
        }
      }
```

Not sure how to provide the right type of parameter for this.

Comment: Try adding a `Failure` as well? Maybe the type is being created at `Success[List[PP]] => Unit` instead of `Try[List[PP]] => Unit`.

Comment: You could also use `pipeTo` pattern as described at http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/actors.html#Ask__Send-And-Receive-Future

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
[scalac] found : akka.actor.Status.Success
```

That means the compiler sees your `Success` and thinks it's an `akka.actor.Status.Success`, when really you mean a `scala.util.Success`. You probably have an import somewhere that is importing the akka Success class.

Either remove the import for `akka.actor.Status.Success`, or resolve the ambiguity by either fully-qualifying the class, or using an import alias, e.g.

```
import scala.util.{Success => ScalaSuccess}

future.onComplete {
  case ScalaSuccess(result) => ...
  // or
  case scala.util.Success(result) => ...
}
```

Comment: The imports were exactly as you stated.  I removed them, imported the correct one, and it worked.  Thank you.